# Unbiased team selection algorithm with squads

Tags: algorithm, probability, game-development

Hi I am currently working on a multiplayer game with the following setup.

Say the game has N players. We want to divide players into two teams, team A and team B where
x < N of the players will be assigned to team A. Additionally before the team division starts a player can join a squad. That is, a player can either choose to play solo or as squad of size 2, 3 or 4. After the team division, players should end up on the same team as their squad members. The algorithm should result in teamA always having x players while having the probability of a player being selected for teamA be the same regardless of whether they are in a squad or not.

The current idea is as follows:

Keep randomly selecting players for teamA until the size of teamA is x. If a randomly selected player is part of a squad of size q > 1 and there is enough room for the whole squad in teamA, add the whole squad to teamA. If there is not enough room for that squad in teamA, all squad members are added to teamB. However since only one squad member needs to be randomly selected, players who are part of squads would be more likely to be selected for teamA. To offset this we first have to pass a check of probability 1/q before adding all the squad members to teamA. If this check fails we do nothing and randomly select another player who has yet to be assigned to teamA. Once we reach x players, all remaining players will be assigned teamB.

The problem is essentially that say N = 100 and x = 25, once 24 players have been selected for team A.
Players who are part of a squad can never be selected since there is no room. As a result, players who are not part of a squad will be assigned to teamA more often.

Wondering if anyone has come across a similar type of problem.

Comment: How would you handle the case where `N = 100`, `x = 25` and you have 25 squads of size 4 each? It would be impossible to place squad members in the same teams.

Comment: Ah that is a good point. In the case where there is no longer enough room to add a squad, that squad is automatically assigned to teamB. Meaning in this case of `N=100` `x=25` with 25 squads of 4 we would end up with 24 players on team A. I suspect there are other such cases but we have to round down to prevent teamA from being larger than x. The other option being allowing 28 players on team A but in the context of the game this is less preferable.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ultimately, this comes down to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). You don't have `N` players to choose from. You have `S` squads to choose from, where `S <= N`. The **sizes** of the squads chosen for team A must sum to `x`. (Players not part of a squad count as a squad of size 1.) There are only so many ways to choose squads for team A such that the number of players on team A is `x`. You *must* choose one of those ways. Therefore, the odds of being on team A are *not* the same for all players. Pure and simple, no way around it.

Comment: An extreme example is `N=7` with `x=3`, with 3 individuals A,B,C, and one squad (D,E,F,G). There's a 100% chance that A,B,C will be on team A, and a 0% chance that D,E,F,G will be on team A.